# SUBSTR and INSTR SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I've started using SUBSTR and INSTR in Oracle but I got confused when I came across this.

```
SELECT PHONE, SUBSTR(PHONE, 1, INSTR(PHONE, '-') -1)
FROM DIRECTORY;
```

So I know SUBSTR cuts values off, and INSTR shows where the occurrence is but the example I've put above has confused me, because the result it 362. When my original value was 362-127-4285. How does that work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`INSTR(PHONE, '-')` gives the **index** of `-` in the `PHONE` column, in your case `4` 
and then `SUBSTR(PHONE, 1, 4 - 1)` or `SUBSTR(PHONE, 1, 3)` 
 gives the **substring** of the `PHONE` column from the `1st` that has length of `3` chars which is `362`, 
if the value `PHONE` column is `362-127-4285`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT PHONE, SUBSTR(PHONE, 1, INSTR(PHONE, '-',1,1) -1)
FROM DIRECTORY;

INSTR(String,'char_Search','position from where start searching','occurance')
```

If We are not giving 'starting position' and 'occurrence' 
it bydefault take as 1,1.

So bydefault it take as INSTR(phone,'-',1,1) --sql returns 1st occurance of string'-' position is 4
and then SUBSTR(PHONE, 1, 4 - 1) which is  SUBSTR(PHONE, 1, 3).

SUBSTR(String,'starting position','no of character')
SUBSTR(PHONE, 1, 3) --gives the substring of the PHONE column from the 1st that has length of 3 chars which is 362

> Ex: using this value--'362-127-4285'

```
SELECT '362-127-4285' Example,
SUBSTR('362-127-4285',1,INSTR('362-127-4285','-')-1) Result 
FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL>select substr('user@example.com',1,instr('user@example.com','@')-1) from dual;
```